# Request header fields too large in localhost Browser Microsoft Edge while I am writing a React app with graphql

Tags: reactjs, api, graphql

I am following a course on Udemy to improve my skills. I was following a lesson about how create an app using react and graphql. I followed the instructions of the lesson, but I can't see anything. I open my console and I found the error: 431 Request Header Fields Too Large.
I try cancel cokkie but **I am on localhost** so not found cookies to clean. Anyone has other ideas? Thank you

Comment: If you open your network panel in your browser, you should see the requests that are being made. From there, you should be able to see the headers you're sending.

Comment: Ok I'll try to follow your instruction, Dan. I hope to answer you soon with good news. I had a screenshot but I can't post because I haven't enough point to share it with the community.